# nm logs not readable - App Store rejection - code obfuscation and selector mangling

Tags: ios, obfuscation, nm

Apple has rejected my app with reason of "code obfuscation and selector mangling" and shared some symbols.

I am able to generate the symbols using “nm” tools but unable to understand the responsible library or code for obfuscation and selector mangling as it’s not in human readable form.

Can any one please help how to decode these symbols to fix this issue?

Below are the symbols:

```
000000010031a98f t +[IjKaMTdiBmyUEmzRylL VraGvFYvdjqlLXdhVelsRTRrrMTg]
000000010031aa16 t +[IjKaMTdiBmyUEmzRylL yzkipWrxGvekULVzaEClYloxPc:]
0000000100306680 t +[JPYsRUnhcXkcbhFfCpmBVl KrPLnmkVgmNrvbJTnCOh:]
0000000100306a53 t +[JPYsRUnhcXkcbhFfCpmBVl MWJWYjjZBnKNeafO]
000000010030678b t +[JPYsRUnhcXkcbhFfCpmBVl PKiqwqAwSWtfneRjYIG:]
000000010030671c t +[JPYsRUnhcXkcbhFfCpmBVl cvWFzeHFliwJzhJMVsxKjKogFUwHJ:]
00000001003061c4 t +[JPYsRUnhcXkcbhFfCpmBVl jIEJcICCOcjIBWAGq]
0000000100306847 t +[JPYsRUnhcXkcbhFfCpmBVl qVgQqfyEyLcyFzhJOSXIDI:]
000000010030828c t +[JqaUyiCsuPNIjrunZQmb initialize]
00000001003122b2 t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh HGNmtEieAezzEeAKKZxEkWExJK:KFwlxngnoHQXWLxECwzRMszKdFUi:]
0000000100311cb0 t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh IdIPwUJSQsrqCnVAvcZxLxqY:qhagKSnZZXLLYqlUKy:GqYTEQVjdKtKzOycFHrLXrNgJusdp:YeUYqjHmIZvTZOWZjysFCdfG:]
0000000100311bc9 t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh IdIPwUJSQsrqCnVAvcZxLxqY:qhagKSnZZXLLYqlUKy:KPZGmDdPTXEhSsrKdegbH:]
0000000100311c3a t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh IdIPwUJSQsrqCnVAvcZxLxqY:qhagKSnZZXLLYqlUKy:YeUYqjHmIZvTZOWZjysFCdfG:]
0000000100311b36 t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh YvfRhvsRhrfFfKbJAKjL:qhagKSnZZXLLYqlUKy:GqYTEQVjdKtKzOycFHrLXrNgJusdp:YeUYqjHmIZvTZOWZjysFCdfG:]
0000000100311a55 t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh YvfRhvsRhrfFfKbJAKjL:qhagKSnZZXLLYqlUKy:KPZGmDdPTXEhSsrKdegbH:]
0000000100311ac3 t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh YvfRhvsRhrfFfKbJAKjL:qhagKSnZZXLLYqlUKy:YeUYqjHmIZvTZOWZjysFCdfG:]
0000000100311d46 t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh cJPzBPeEdWulAkQpGOsD:FxzVLwnyqhjxgmfDpnQBHxEd:qhagKSnZZXLLYqlUKy:GqYTEQVjdKtKzOycFHrLXrNgJusdp:YeUYqjHmIZvTZOWZjysFCdfG:]
00000001003118eb t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh dUtuAxuOXveDykrUfptlk:qhagKSnZZXLLYqlUKy:KPZGmDdPTXEhSsrKdegbH:]
00000001003119a2 t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh dUtuAxuOXveDykrUfptlk:qhagKSnZZXLLYqlUKy:YeUYqjHmIZvTZOWZjysFCdfG:]
0000000100311f3f t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh uQjMwMrdxkIlKWa:XaOnqcHsSYzwdQEMDQHAbcJ:tHnhXMsqfoBEYUWAZJRlTtxVsbV:tsZYUcfLzTSodjJbsZwODCskwQYR:]
000000010031210d t +[KYJnOppaDkWpiqedFmkDWXFFpAsHh wcBIhyLGNyTlxxOqdev:]
```

Comment: You found out solution?

Comment: @LalitKumar Sorry for late reply. Well, not directly but I had to remove suspected libraries one by one and on third attempt I found the culprit. It was a third party security framework responsible for these code obfuscation and selector mangling.
We worked together to fix those issues and resubmitted the app and it got approved.

Comment: can you please explain or share the link on generating the symbols using “nm” tools